# Node rating like in Google Places?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps

Is there any tool or node/way tag in OpenStreetMap to obtain a POI rate as with the Google Places service? (here nodes/places have a label/tag with the rating. e.g. `<rating>3.2</rating>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such rating implemented in Openstreetmap data. And I doubt if there ever will be, as one of the principles of OSM is to tag objective things. And rating is not objective at all. It will only be attractive for spammers.